# Can Azure connect to a non-"Azure Connect" IPsec VPN?

Tags: azure, connect, vpn

I have an IPsec VPN (also PPTP if that works better) that I need my Azure roles to be able to connect into. I can't use Windows Azure Connect since I don't have any ability to reconfigure the VPN or its host machine; it is provided by a vendor.

Is it possible to ask Azure roles to connect into the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because IPsec and PPTP both require other protocols besides TCP/IP.

An TCP-based VPN solution like OpenVPN would work, however.

Comment: @everwicked: Unfortunately this wasn't an option with the vendor either.

Comment: David, just in case you are interested, I figured out a solution that I'm going to use on a similar problem. First, I will have an in-house processor that connects through the VPN to the vendor and retrieves whatever info is necessary. I will use an Azure Service Bus Queue to post the requests and retrieve the responses. Not a perfect solution, but a working one, until there's an alternative. Let me know if you want more details.

Comment: @everwicked: Unfortunately we don't have an "in house" to host things in -- we're entirely cloud based. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

Can you ask your vendor to install Windows Azure Connect endpoint software? You just need to give him the install link; he can launch the install using the install link, it is a one-click process. This is probably the easiest and most reliable way to enable your scenario. It is a huge task if not impossible to setup VPN manually on the Azure machine to connect to your local VPN server, and remember you will need to set that for each role instance. Ask your vendor to click the install link for Connect endpoint is the way to go.

Comment: No, as I mentioned Windows Azure Connect is *not* an option in this scenario.